# What will happen if an ideal current source is connected to a isolated resistance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

I know that ideal current source is a theoretical thing. But when it comes to solve problems we have to consider these scenarios. Now suppose an ideal current source is connected with an isolated resistance; now what should happen; should the current flow in the resistance?

I am asking as an isolated resistance has infinite potential now the ideal current source which is connected at its another end has also infinite resistance so what do I make out of it should the current flow or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "theoretically ideal" world,  an "ideal current source" has infinite voltage available, so it can assert its current flow through an infinite resistance- like the case where the other leg of the resistor is not connected to the return port of the current source.

In the real world: unless the current path is from the current source, through the resistor, and then back to the current source in a complete loop, no current will flow because no one has on their lab bench a current source that can push any amount of current through several million ohms of resistance in an *open circuit*.

Comment: JUST asking :-So when you have open air at the other end of the resistance then if you put a lot of voltage then the air should polarize to create a potential difference to create the current?

Comment: No, what will happen is when the voltage gets big enough (millions of volts perhaps) the air will get ionized and start conducting electricity from the other end of the resistor to wherever zero potential (ground) is. In other words, LIGHTNING with a big kaboom!

Comment: Maybe not even a lightning: rather an arc, since the current source is ideal, so it will maintain the current instead of losing the charge as e.g. the clouds do.

Comment: @ruslan, you might be right, in any case the result will be exciting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a eminently practical answer.

You simply compute the capacitance of the open circuit (everything has one) and then treat it like any other RC circuit connected to a ideal DC power supply.

For practical circuits, however, even with a large resistance the time constant is shorter than your sampling oscilloscope can measure. So you aren't going to find it easy to observer the transient behavior.

Comment: No, I mean the capacitance of the open circuit. This is a well defined quantity with exactly the same semantics as a made to purpose capacitor, but it generally has a very small value (attafarads or less).

Comment: please give some reference on how to calculate it.

Comment: That's non-trivial. We did some "easy" cases in my upper-division E&M in college and some harder one in graduate E&M. But it comes down to computing the ratio of charge to voltage just like you do for a parallel-plate or cylindrical capacitor. The issue is that for a random open circuit the geometry doesn't have the nice structure of built-to-purpose devices.

Comment: all i need is a multimeter to calculate the potential of open circuit  ? And can be done if you are doing it in practical.  And in case of charge i would take a capacitor which would induce the same charge and find the potential by multimeter to find the charge (due to fact i know the capacitance of the known capacitor i will come to know the charge).  Should this process be perfect?

Comment: @Nobody, your multimeter probably only has an equivalent resistance of 10 megohms or so, so it will disturb the system.

Comment: @ThePhoton lets go for potentiometer then. I think thatll be the best.